# How do I decode a machine instruction to assembly in LEGv8?

Tags: assembly, arm64, instructions, instruction-set, machine-code

I am having trouble figuring out how a LEGv8 machine instruction is decoded. Assume the following binary:

**1000 1011 0000 1111 0000 0000 0001 0011**

I have the following chart that is supposed to help me decode:

[image: LEGv8 instruction encoding/decoding chart]

The first 11 bits **10001011000** correspond to decimal **1112** and according to the chart this is the **ADD** instruction. So I know how to determine this part of the instruction (unless there is a better approach, maybe this won't work for opcodes that aren't 11 bits?). At this point I am confused on how to proceed.

I know that ADD is of instruction format **R-format** so the bits are layed out as below:

opcode: 11 bits
Rm: 5 bits
shamt: 6 bits
Rn: 5 bits
Rd: 5 bits

I attempt to lay out the initial binary machine instruction knowing these field sizes...

opcode = **1000 1011 000**0 1111 0000 0000 0001 0011 = **10001011000**
This is the first 11 bits of the initial binary machine instruction.

Rm = 1000 1011 000**0 1111** 0000 0000 0001 0011 = **01111**
This is the next 5 bits after the initial 11 bits for opcode.

shamt = 1000 1011 0000 1111 **0000 00**00 0001 0011 = **000000**
This is the next 6 bits after the 5 bits for Rm.

Rn = 1000 1011 0000 1111 0000 00**00 000**1 0011 = **00000**
This is the next 5 bits after the 6 bits for shamt.

Rd = 1000 1011 0000 1111 0000 0000 000**1 0011** = **10011**
This is the last 5 bits in the binary machine instruction (the 5 bits after the 5 bits for Rn).

Converting binary to decimal for the Rm, Rn and Rd I get:

Rm = 15 = **X15**
Rn = 0 = **X0**
Rd = 19 = **X19**

Therefore my final answer to decoding the initial binary machine instruction to an assembly statement would be **ADD X19, X0, X15**

However the textbook answer where this example is from is **ADD X16, X15, X5**. Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your solution seems to be correct, and also matches output produced by gnu binutils:

```
$ echo .int 0b10001011000011110000000000010011 > test.s
$ as test.s && objdump -d a.out

a.out:     file format elf64-littleaarch64
Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000000 <.text>:
   0:   8b0f0013    add x19, x0, x15
```

Books are known to contain errors ;)

Comment: I strived a lot until someone suggested to `strip` the code.
`$ echo .word 0b10001011000011110000000000010011 > test.s`

`$ aarch64-linux-gnu-as test.s && aarch64-linux-gnu-strip a.out && aarch64-linux-gnu-objdump -d a.out`

`0: 8b0f0013  add x19, x0, x15`